# 503 Service Unavailable on Azure Cloud App

Tags: azure, hosting, azure-web-roles

I have the strange problem, that began near one week ago. I have the site, hosted as a cloud app (a webrole with at least 2 instances running, auto scaling up to 4 max) in Azure. And from time to time when I open it I get 503 Service Unavailable error. But if I will refresh the page, site will open without any errors. QA site at the same time works without any problems. May you know why it's going on? Thanks!

Comment: are you doing any request logging to determine if the request is being received by the web role?

Comment: Only logging in IIS. I'm sorry for the late answer.

Comment: we've been fighting 503's in websites and cloud service web roles for weeks. IIS logs show no requests hitting the sites during those times. Did you ever get anywhere with your issue @DenHaydash ?

Answer (score 0):

503s in Azure App Services are one of these three:

- You've reached the quota for the underlying app service plan (obviously doesn't apply to a premium plan)
- You're using deployment slots and hitting a slot that is missing code (if the slots are 50%/50% or something like that it would explain why the 503 is intermittent)
- Remote Debugger is preventing port binding of the application. Try disabling Remote Debugging and restarting the app service.